# How to replace a string while while keeping a part of it using regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have file with multiple records:
for example:

```
"datetime": "2018-10-10"
"datetime": "2018-10-11"
"datetime": "2019-01-11"
"datetime": "2018-02-15"
```

I would like to replace this string such that i can retain the date values, so something of this sort:

```
"datetime": date("2018-10-10")
"datetime": date("2018-10-11")
"datetime": date("2019-01-11")
"datetime": date("2018-02-15")
```

I am able to use `"datetime": ".*"` to find the above records, but am stuck with replacing them in the above format
help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

**Find what**: `("datetime": )(".*")`
**Replace with**: `\1date\(\2\)`

**Details**

- `("datetime": )` - Group 1 (`\1` in the replacement pattern): a literal `"datetime":`  substring
- `(".*")` - Group 2 (`\2` in the replacement pattern): `"`, any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, and then a `"` (note that in case your contents are mixed, it is much safer to use a non-greedy pattern here, `".*?"`)

Note that `(` and `)` inside the replacement pattern must be escaped as Notepad++ regex replacement patterns are Boost conditional replacement patterns and parentheses are "special" there.

[image]

Comment: How do we go about doing the the following :

From the below string : 

"datetime": "date(2018-10-10)"
"datetime": "date(2018-10-11)"
"datetime": "date(2019-01-11)"
"datetime": "date(2018-02-15)"

To:
"datetime": date("2018-10-10")
"datetime": date("2018-10-11")
"datetime": date("2019-01-11")
"datetime": date("2018-02-15")

Comment: @SayantanRoy Search for `("datetime"\h*:\h*)"(date\()([^()]*)(\))"` and replace with `$1$2"$3"$4`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/aP7GQf/1).